# Woocommerce - Second T&C checkbox doesn't prevent checkout when left unchecked

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, hook

I have a special checkbox I need placed only if the customer purchases one of two specific products. Code below looks for these product_ids, and if found, displays the additional Terms and Conditions box next to the regular T&C checkbox. While this part is working, the checkout still completes even if the box is left unchecked, so I'm guessing the problem is within the `aym_not_approved_amb_terms()` function, but I can't seem to figure out what that problem is.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'aym_add_ambassador_terms_box' );
function aym_add_ambassador_terms_box() {
    // set product IDs:
    $product_ids = array( 17558, 17563 );
    $bool = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $item = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( in_array( $item->id, $product_ids ) )
            $bool = true;
    }
    // If product IDs detected
    if ($bool)
        // add ambassador terms checkbox
            add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'aym_add_checkout_tickbox' );

            function aym_add_checkout_tickbox() {
        echo '<script>console.log("checkbox")</script>';

                echo '<p class="form-row-wide terms">';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="amb-terms-check" id="amb-terms-check" />';
                echo '<label for="amb-terms-check" class="checkbox">I accept Ambassador terms and Conditions</label>';
                echo '</p>';

            }

            // Show notice if customer does not tick

            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'aym_not_approved_amb_terms');

            function aym_not_approved_amb_terms() {
                if ( ! $_POST['amb-terms-check'] )
                    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please agree to the Ambassador Terms and Conditions' ), 'error' );
            }

}
```

Expected behavior: if the box is left unchecked, page scrolls back up to the error message area and displays the message 'Please agree to the Ambassador Terms and Conditions'. Maybe I'm not using the correct hook for the `aym_not_approved_amb_terms` function...?

Comment: Because your validation is inside a conditional that only loads once the form is loaded, your validation callback doesn't exist when the form is actually being validated. That seemed cleared in my brain, so I hope it made sense. I am working up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your validation is inside a conditional that only loads once the form is loaded, your validation callback doesn't exist when the form is actually being validated.

So what we're going to do is unwrap the `add_action()` calls from inside the conditional check and put the conditional check inside the callbacks. Now, this kinda means we have to check the cart twice, and I think there must be a more efficient way to do this but I thought about adding a flag in the cart when the item is added, however the cart classes magic `__get()` method will now prevent `$cart->my_flag` from returning any useful values. SO, we'll just check the cart twice for now.

Since we will check the cart twice, I extrapolated your conditional out into a function that we can reuse.

```
function aym_is_item_in_cart() {

    $matching_product_ids = array( 17558, 17563 );

    $bool = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $matching_product_ids ) ) {
            $bool = true;
        }
    }
    return $bool;
}
```

Then we add the checkbox. In WooCommerce 3.0, I found an [issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14792) where the field was repeating when adding to the `woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total` hook, so I've added it to the `woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details` instead. note how I'm always adding the callback to this hook, but the checkbox is inside a conditional. Also note that I'm using the built-in `woocommerce_form_field()` helper function to create the form field instead of adding it via javascript.

```
// add ambassador terms checkbox
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'aym_maybe_add_ambassador_terms_box', 5 );

function aym_maybe_add_ambassador_terms_box() {

    // If product IDs detected
    if ( aym_is_item_in_cart() ) {

    $checkout = WC()->checkout();

        $field = array(
            'type'              => 'checkbox',
            'label'             => __( 'I accept Ambassador terms and Conditions', 'your-plugin' ),
            'required'          => true,
            'class'             => array( 'form-row-wide', 'terms'),
            'validate'          => array( 'terms' ),
        );

        woocommerce_form_field( 'amb-terms-check', $field, $checkout->get_value( 'amb-terms-check' ) );

    }

}
```

Lastly, some validation. We need to check if we need the checkbox and then check if it's checked, otherwise this will block checkouts that don't have the triggering products in the checkout.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'aym_not_approved_amb_terms' );

function aym_not_approved_amb_terms() {

    if ( aym_is_item_in_cart() && ! isset( $_POST['amb-terms-check'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please agree to the Ambassador Terms and Conditions' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer... Thank you for helping me to both solve the problem to further my understanding.